# sql "chain of command"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I imagine this is a normal sort of query to need but sometimes you have to know the common name given to a problem to be able find more information about solving it.  I call it the 'chain of command' problem.

I have the following table structure:

```
create table employee_boss_history (
  name nvarchar(50),
  boss nvarchar(50),
  start_date date,
  end_date date  
);
```

And the following sample data:

```
insert into employee_boss_history (name, boss, start_date, end_date)
VALUES 
('Bill',   null,   '2002-01-01', '2016-03-01'),
('Will',  'Bill',  '2015-03-02', '2016-03-01'),
('Will',   null,   '2016-03-02', null),
('Mark',  'Bill',  '2003-01-01', '2006-12-31'),
('Mark',  'Bill',  '2012-01-01', '2016-03-01'),
('Mark',  'Will',  '2016-03-02', '2016-04-30'),
('Ross',  'Will',  '2016-05-01', null),
('Roger', 'Bill',  '2006-01-01', '2012-03-01'),
('Roger', 'Mark',  '2012-03-02', '2012-09-30'),
('Kris',  'Mark',  '2012-10-01', '2016-04-30'),
('Kris',  'Ross',  '2016-05-01', '2017-01-31'),
('Moe',   'Ross',  '2017-03-01', null),
('Rich',  'Roger', '2006-03-01', '2012-09-30'),
('Rich',  'Kris',  '2012-10-01', '2017-01-31'),
('Rich',  'Ross',  '2017-02-01', '2017-02-28'),
('Rich',  'Moe',   '2017-03-01',  null)
```

This (fake) data represents when someone's manager changed.

What I would like to do is have a query that would take each the entire table and build out all of their chains of command.  There should be one row per employee and chain of command and it should have the earliest date and latest date that the chain of command was in effect for.  If anyone in their chain of command changes, then they should have another chain of command record added.

For example, Rich has had four different managers, but at least six different changes in his command structure over time.  Maybe more, I was trying to work it out by hand.

```
start_date  end_date    chain_of_command
2006-03-01  2013-03-01  Rich | Roger | Bill
2012-03-02  2012-09-30  Rich | Roger | Mark | Bill
2012-10-01  2016-04-30  Rich | Kris | Mark | Bill
2016-05-01  2017-01-31  Rich | Kris | Ross | Will
2017-02-01  2017-02-28  Rich | Ross | Will
2017-03-01  NULL        Rich | Moe | Ross | Will
```

I've got a CTE already developed whereby I can pass in a person and a date, and it will walk the adjacency list and show the hierarchy on that date.  It works, but I'm trying to build a summary like the above.

Pointers to a solution gratefully accepted, or if there's more reading I should be doing (Is this considered gaps and islands?), please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You are looking for a Recursive CTE. These are used to deal with Hierarchical data (Chain of command). It's going to get ugly with your date logic though and I do not envy you. It's not a gap and island issue though.

Comment: This is not the gaps and islands thing, I'd say it resembles more of a bill-of-materials. But I'm not sure about the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code will do the trick. I first change NULL into a future date to simplify things, then start recursing into the hierarchy. The recursion ends when we have a "NULL boss".

The outer query then just selects those "NULL bosses", else it would return the intermediate steps.

```
WITH d AS(
    SELECT name, boss, start_date, ISNULL(end_date, '99991231') end_date
    FROM employee_boss_history
),
r AS (
    SELECT start_date, end_date, name, boss,
        CAST(name AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS chain_of_command
    FROM d
    WHERE name = 'Rich'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CASE WHEN d.start_date > r.start_date THEN d.start_date ELSE r.start_date END,
        CASE WHEN d.end_date < r.end_date THEN d.end_date ELSE r.end_date END,
        d.name,
        d.boss,
        CAST(CONCAT_WS(' | ', chain_of_command, d.name) AS VARCHAR(1000))
    FROM d
    INNER JOIN r
        ON d.name = r.boss
            AND r.start_date <= d.end_date
            AND r.end_date >= d.start_date
)

SELECT start_date, end_date, chain_of_command
FROM r
WHERE boss IS NULL
ORDER BY start_date;
```

Comment: If you want to have a NULL instead of 9999-12-31 in the last row, change the end_date column in the last SELECT to `NULLIF(end_date, '99991231') AS end_date`.

Comment: Solved.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a first pass at using a Recursive CTE to attack this.

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        name as starting_name,
        name, 
        boss, 
        start_Date, 
        end_date, 
        CAST(name as VARCHAR(200)) as coc, 
        1 as depth
    FROM employee_boss_history
    WHERE name = 'Rich'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        recCTE.starting_name,
        ebh.name,
        ebh.boss,
        CASE WHEN recCTE.start_date < ebh.start_date THEN ebh.start_date ELSE recCTE.start_Date END,
        CASE WHEN recCTE.end_date > ebh.end_date THEN ebh.end_date ELSE recCTE.end_Date END,
        cast(recCTE.coc + ' | ' + ebh.name as varchar(200)),
        recCTE.depth  +  1  
    FROM recCTE
        INNER JOIN employee_boss_history ebh ON
             recCTE.boss = ebh.name AND
             recCTE.start_date <= ebh.end_date AND
             recCTE.end_Date >= ebh.start_date
  )
  SELECT starting_name, coc as chain_of_command, start_date, end_date, depth FROM recCTE;
```

Recursive CTE's are broken into two parts.

1. The "Anchor". This is the stuff above the UNION. It defines the starting point for the recursion. In this case records for Bill.
2. The "Recursive" portion. Here we refer back to the CTE that we are in and join it to the table. Child/Name to Parent/Boss. We have to take the added steps here of rectifying our intersecting date periods and go through some ugly CASE logic to insure we are properly truncating that period to where the relationship between employee/boss is true for the entire chain of command.

The last but just selects from the CTE. You'll see you get a record back for every step of the recursion, but... I think this will get you close to where you need to be.

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eacce/17)

```
+---------------+----------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| starting_name |      chain_of_command      | start_date | end_date  | depth |
+---------------+----------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| Rich          | Rich                       | 3/1/2006   | 9/30/2012 |     1 |
| Rich          | Rich                       | 10/1/2012  | 1/31/2017 |     1 |
| Rich          | Rich                       | 2/1/2017   | 2/28/2017 |     1 |
| Rich          | Rich                       | 3/1/2017   | (null)    |     1 |
| Rich          | Rich | Kris                | 10/1/2012  | 4/30/2016 |     2 |
| Rich          | Rich | Kris                | 5/1/2016   | 1/31/2017 |     2 |
| Rich          | Rich | Kris | Mark         | 10/1/2012  | 3/1/2016  |     3 |
| Rich          | Rich | Kris | Mark         | 3/2/2016   | 4/30/2016 |     3 |
| Rich          | Rich | Kris | Mark | Bill  | 10/1/2012  | 3/1/2016  |     4 |
| Rich          | Rich | Roger               | 3/1/2006   | 3/1/2012  |     2 |
| Rich          | Rich | Roger               | 3/2/2012   | 9/30/2012 |     2 |
| Rich          | Rich | Roger | Mark        | 3/2/2012   | 9/30/2012 |     3 |
| Rich          | Rich | Roger | Mark | Bill | 3/2/2012   | 9/30/2012 |     4 |
| Rich          | Rich | Roger | Bill        | 3/1/2006   | 3/1/2012  |     3 |
+---------------+----------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: Nice to see the anchor/recursive parts of the CTE called out. I found this confusing when I first started trying to understand CTE examples.